# Нельзя добавить источник данных в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite

В Visual Studio 2015 Express или Community при создании проекта "Универсальное пустое приложение Windows C++" не получается создать источник данных.
В случае Express версии нету ни пункта меню "Данные", ни окна "Источник данных" Сочетание клавиш Alt+Shift+D не открывает окно. В Пункте меню "Вид" тоже нету.
В версии "Community" нету пункта меню "Данные", но есть уже открытое окно "Источник данных. Только вот кнопки интерфейса этого окна не активны а при ПКМ в контекстном меню ничего не выбрать.
Вопрос, как создать источник данных и подключить sql, если это все не работает. Может это не доступно в универсальных приложениях windows? Если так, то как использовать тот же sqlite?

PS: Использую именно 2015 версию для кроссплатформенности - телефонов windows и PC.

Answer (score 1):

Решил часть проблемы перейдя на C# (был не критичен выбор языка). Нашел статью по этой [**ссылке**](http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/Using-SQLITE-in-Windows-10-IoT-Core-Insider-Preview/).
Если обобщить, то нужно скачать библиотеку с сайта SQLite для нужной разрядности и закинуть в папку bin к списку библиотек (не забыть ссылку в проекте на эту библиотеку "sqlite3.dll"). Так же в NuGet поставить расширение SQLite.Net-PCL (кстати, на языке C++ почему то не подключалось, может не поддерживается для C++). Пример кода для работы с SQLite большой. Все есть по ссылке выше.

Answer (score 0):

Например, если подключить MySQL, используются коннекторы...

А вот API для SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).